# Random numbers in my array are filled by last one randomed

Tags: c#, arrays, random, numbers

I created program in which user can choose how many numbers have array and this array should have random values. Well, it doesn't. To check after each try to sign number to each array argument I make console.writeline to show which number was randomly assigned. And at the end entire array is filled by last one randomed this method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Set the number of arguments in mineArray:");
    string argumentsNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    int argumentsNumberInt = Convert.ToInt32(argumentsNumber);
    int[] mineArray = new int[argumentsNumberInt];
    Random rand = new Random();

    //set up values to each index of array
    foreach (int i in mineArray)
    {
        mineArray[] = rand.Next(1, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + mineArray[i]);
    }
    string a = "asd";

    foreach (int k in mineArray)
    {
        if (mineArray[k] % 3 == 0 || mineArray[k] % 5 == 0)
        {
            if (mineArray[k] % 3 == 0 && mineArray[k] % 5 == 0)
            {
                a = "Able to divide by 3 and 5";
            }
            else
            {
                if (mineArray[k] % 3 == 0) { a = "Able to divide only by 3"; }
                if (mineArray[k] % 5 == 0) { a = "Able to divide only by 5"; }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            a = "Number unable to divide";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(mineArray[k] + " " + a);
    }
```

Comment: What `mineArray[] = rand.Next(1, 10);` supposed to mean?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Believe he meant `mineArray[i]...`

Comment: you should use a normal `for` loop to set values, as `foreach` is just a readonly function

Comment: Yeah, sorry i've deleted it accidentially before posting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you do `mineArray[i] = rand.Next(1, 10);`, otherwise this wouldn't compile (your code is missing the `i`).

The problem is in your foreach loop:

```
int[] mineArray = new int[argumentsNumberInt];
Random rand = new Random();

//set up values to each index of array
foreach (int i in mineArray)
```

This `foreach` will run through an array filled with zeroes, every time assigning the random variable to `mineArray [0]`.

Use `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argumentsNumberInt; i++)
```

Comment: You guys are incredible. Five minutes and I know hundred times more than by guessing what I've messed up. :)

Comment: Learning to use breakpoints and the [various debug windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62.aspx) could come in handy in cases like this. :)